# "Wrapping" heatmap columns in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm working on creating a heatmap of objects in a shelving unit using RStudio. The way the shelving is configured IRL is one column is shelves #1-8 from top to bottom, next column is shelves #9-16 top to bottom, and so on, for 54 total shelving units, repeated for 6 aisles of shelving. I'm attempting to create a visual layout in R that mimics that same setup for a data set that includes variables for Row number, Shelf number, and count of objects for that Row-Shelf. I would like the heat map to "wrap" so that there is a column mapping shelves 1-8, followed by a column mapping shelves 9-16, and so on. Is this possible? Here is a section of the data as an example:

```
# A tibble: 274 × 3
# Groups:   Row [6]
     Row Shelf count
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1     4
 2     1     2     5
 3     1     3     2
 4     1     4     4
 5     1     5     3
 6     1     6     1
 7     1     7     6
 8     1     8     7
 9     1     9     9
10     1    10     3
# ℹ 264 more rows
```

I have this code for a heatmap of one full aisle of shelving in a single column:

```
  ggplot(data = dupesSorted %>% filter(Row==1),
       aes(x = Row, y = Shelf, fill = count)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'yellow', high = 'red', na.value = 'gray')+
  geom_text(aes(label = count))+
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(1, 54, by = 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 6, by = 1))
```

And this code for a separate heatmap of what I would like the initial column to be:

```
  ggplot(data = dupesSorted %>% filter(Row==1, Shelf<8),
       aes(x = Row, y = Shelf, fill = count)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'yellow', high = 'red', na.value = 'gray')+
  geom_text(aes(label = count))+
    scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(1, 8, by = 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 6, by = 1))
```

Here's the output of the second code snippet:[heatmap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFAOS.png)

What I would like to do, if possible is to create a heatmap on that same scale that progresses through all 54 shelves, in columns of 8.

I've tried using the facet_wrap() function by adding
 `facet_wrap(~Shelf, ncol=6)`
to the ggplot function, but that separated the visualization into 54 separate boxes, one for *each* shelf, and then separated *those* visualizations into 6 columns. Is there a way to create one continuous visualization, but with a break to a new column at specified intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I create some fake data (fyi for future questions it's good practice to include some to reduce ambiguity and make it easier for people to help) and pre-calculate where I want the data to appear, using R's modulo and integer division operators.

```
dupesSorted <- data.frame(
  Row = rep(1:6, each = 54),
  Shelf = rep(1:54, times = 6),
  count = rpois(54*6, 7)
)

dupesSorted |> 
  mutate(x_pos = (Shelf - 1) %/% 8 + 1,
         y_pos = (Shelf - 1)  %% 8 + 1) |>
  ggplot(aes(x_pos, y_pos, fill = count)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'yellow', high = 'red', na.value = 'gray')+
  geom_text(aes(label = count))+
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(1, 54, by = 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 6, by = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~Row)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, this is just what I was looking for - this is just enough to get me started, I can figure out how to customize the rest of the elements I need to adjust from here. Thank you so much!